# How to add attributes ColdFusion tags in bulk

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I was curious if there is a way to force a ColdFusion tag to hold an attribute as default, such as the datasource in cfquery.

For example instead of writing

```
   <cfquery datasource="mydatasource">
```

I can write

```
   <cfquery>
```

and the system automatically knows that the datasource is "mydatasource".

Would be really cool if this was possible.

Comment: You should specify which version of ColdFusion you are using.

Comment: Across 8/9/10. But for our purposes we can stick with 9.

Answer (score 6):

It is actually possible for datasource, but not for everything.

You may set a `this.datasource="mydatasource"` as the default datasource in your `Application.cfc`

https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Application+variables

Comment: Is there a way to add other attributes? For example adding cachedwithin

Comment: Everything I've read indicates the answer to that is a no. Why would you want to cache every single query the same amount of time, anyway?

Comment: @RobinSaunders have you used `attributeCollection`? http://www.aliaspooryorik.com/blog/index.cfm/e/posts.details/post/passing-sql-to-cfquery-using-attributecollection-331

Comment: @TRose Just curiosity :P

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan No, but that is a good tool for down the road! ty!

Answer (score 1):

The practical answer to your question are the `custom tags`. You can extend the features of ColdFusion tags to match your needs.

Taking into example the `cfquery` tag and wrapping a custom tag around it. Provide all the default values you want for the parameters of the `cfquery` into the tag's attribute default.

So essentially your custom tag page would be something like:

### flexiquery.cfm

```
<cfif THISTAG.ExecutionMode EQ 'end'>
    <cfparam name="Attributes.datasource" default="someDSN">
    <cfparam name="Attributes.cacheWithin" default="#CreateTimeSpan(0,6,0,0)#">
    <cfparam name="Attributes.maxRows" default="25">
    <cfparam name="Attributes.timeOut" default="600">
    <!--- some logic you want to perform --->
    <cfquery datasource="#Attributes.datasource#"
             cacheWithin="#Attributes.cacheWithin#"
             maxRow="#Attributes.maxRows#"
             timeOut="#Attributes.timeOut#"
          <cfoutput>#THISTAG.GeneratedContent#</cfoutput>
    </cfquery>
    <!--- Caller assignment and other processing --->
</cfif>
```

And now you can use it and re-use it across your project, the way you wanted and even overriding the value you want to be different:

```
<cf_flexiquery>
  <!--- you query here --->
</cf_flexiquery>
```

or

```
<cf_flexiquery maxRows="100" timeOut="1200">
  <!--- you query here --->
</cf_flexiquery>
```

It gives you a fair idea of how to go with it. I have extended the custom tags features to leverage the features of `cfhttp`, `cfpdf`, `cffile` etc.

This is only way you can adopt the flexibility you want with ColdFusion tags and it works perfectly.

Comment: I do not have time to try it, but what happens if they are using cfqueryparam?

Comment: I suspect it would throw an error for cfqueryparam.  However, this is a good answer.  The question was general in nature.  Cfquery was stated as an example.

Comment: There's a solution for that as well. You can create your own child sub tag like `<cf_flexiqueryparam>`. The handling of data it passes to the parent and the actual binding of these parameters inside the parent tag is very interesting topic in itself.

Comment: But it's possible to make your parent-child relationship inside custom tags perform the way `cfquery` and `cfqueryparam` does or on the similar line for http tags `cfhttp` and `cfhttpparam` and mail tags.

Comment: *You can create your own child sub tag* - @Anurag - Sure, but my question was does that structure actually work with `cfqueryparam`? Normally, CF complains if you try and use that tag outside a `cfquery`, like in this case. I am curious if you actually verified it works with `cfqueryparam`.

Comment: No it doesn't work with `cfqueryparam`. The solution skeleton in the answer will only work with prepared query without `cfqueryparam`. It was just for the idea. But it is possible to create a custom relationship between our custom parent/child tags to work the same way `cfquery` and `cfqueryparam` does. I can say for sure as I have build one such custom solution. But yes @Leigh it won't work with the 'cfqueryparam` in the query. I should have been clearer in the comment.

Comment: As you said, it won't work outside its parent tag, so we cannot read the query string with a `cfqueryparam` in it likewise for the other tag relationships such as: `cfhttp`/`cfhttpparam`, `cfmail`/`cfmailparam` and few others.